# Real-time form field update based on the selection of the form's drop-down menu

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I created a form in Excel VBA: when the form is triggered, it's initialized and some cells are pre-filled with a suggested input.

Is it possible to update a pre-filled input based on the selection of the form's drop-down menu (which can change as long as the form is open), i.e. it initializes once but then updates a field in the form (in real time) based on the input of another field in that same form?

Specifically, if sourceDropDown.value = "A" then orderQty = 1.
If sourceDropDown.Value is changed to "B" in the form, then orderQty is updated to 2.

```vb
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim orderQty As Double
    Dim group As String
    Dim orderDate As Date
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet

    orderQty = findQuantity
    group = findGroup
    orderDate = findDate

    purchOrd.value = ""
    
    sourceDropDown.Clear
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sources")
    With wsSource
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    sourceDropDown.List = wsSource.range("A1:A" & lastRow).value

    mmCode.value = ""
        
    releaseDate.value = orderDate
    
    orderQuantity.value = orderQty
    
    purchOrd.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you can use the events associated with `sourceDropDown` ... assuming this is a Control on the UserForm then in the UserForm's code-behind, in the top/left drop-down (just at the top of the code window) select `sourceDropDown` then in the top/right drop-down select an event eg if `sourceDropDown` is a ComboBox then you might use the `Change` event ... you can add whatever code you need within the event handler, for example to update the value of other Controls, cells in Worksheets etc

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate your explanation!! This works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the events associated with `sourceDropDown` ... assuming this is a Control on the UserForm then in the UserForm's code-behind, in the top/left drop-down (just at the top of the code window) select `sourceDropDown` then in the top/right drop-down select an event eg if `sourceDropDown` is a ComboBox then you might use the `Change` event ... you can add whatever code you need within the event handler, for example to update the value of other Controls, cells in Worksheets etc